# Wine On Solus Not Working

Tags: linux, software-installation, wine, solus

I've tried to download wine through the launch software center and by typing

```
sudo eopkg install wine
```

In the terminal with no result. I want to play games with wine and it worked on ubuntu. But not on Solus. It says is downloaded but i can't find it/select it.

Answer (score 2):

WINE doesn't provide any application launchers by itself. You must run other programs *through* wine, i.e. via the command line or double clicking on the .exe file.

Note that the "wine" package is the native architecture package, and provides the command "wine64". For the "wine" command, which is 32-bit only, you must install "wine-32bit".